# How to remove ubuntu from dual booted system?

Tags: system-installation

I have windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.
i am getting some sudo error so need to reinstall ubuntu.
How to keep windows running?
I do not have any windows bootloader on a cd

Comment: You can try solving sudo error instead of reinstalling ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and 10 have a utility to create a "rescue" disk. Usually you write it to a DVD.
have a look at the steps here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/

I prefer to write mine to a DVD instead of a USB drive. I do use an external USB HD to backup the entire system image.